# Validar registros en una tabla de baremos en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo validar en una tabla con datos para un Baremo.

```
IdBaremo    IdProducto  Desde   Hasta   Precio
316         469         1       20000   0,83
317         469         20001   25000   0,74
318         469         25001   30000   0,59
319         469         30001   40000   0,47
320         469         40001   NULL    0,44
```

Realmente necesito validar que el siguiente valor 'DESDE' no sea igual o menor que el valor 'HASTA' del registro anterior (PREVIO) por ejemplo que el valor 25001  del 3er registro de DESDE no sea igual menor que el 25000 del HASTA del 2do registro. Me vale como salida de validación un mensaje de aviso con un simple print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si dispones de un Sql Server 2012 o superior, puedes utilizar la función LAG.

```
create table baremos
(IdBaremo int, IdProducto int, Desde int, Hasta int,  Precio float)
go
insert into baremos
(IdBaremo, IdProducto, Desde, Hasta, Precio)
values
(316,469 ,1    ,20000,0.83),
(317,469 ,20001,25000,0.74),
(318,469 ,25001,30000,0.59),
(319,469 ,30001,40000,0.47),
(320,469 ,40001,NULL ,0.44);
go
;with cte as (
    SELECT *,
    LAG (HASTA,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY IdBaremo) AS ANT
FROM 
baremos
)
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Desde > ANT THEN 'No' ELSE 'Si' end AS Valido
FROM CTE
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Lag y Lead](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lag-y-lead-siguiente-y-anterior/)

Comment: Muchas gracias.